# (Why) Do N trials of a B.P. reduce variance by a factor of N?

Tags: variance

This question arrises from the lecture of a book called "Data mining" by Witten and Frank. I try to understand a statement and there is one point I just do not understand nor do I find any explanation:

We are considering a Bernoulli process which has a success rate p and thus mean p and variance p(1-p). So far so good. Now the text says

> If N trials are taken from a Bernoulli process, the expected success
>   rate f=S/N is a random variable with the same mean p; the variance is
>   reduced by a factor of N to p(1-p)/N.

Now why is that?

If this question is trivial please excuse. I am not a mathematician but a physicist trying to get some knowledge in Data Science.

Thanks in advance!

Btw: I found this question here already but it makes me even more confused: [Variance of n Bernoulli Trials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/466843/variance-of-n-bernoulli-trials)

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variance and expected value are additive. So the expected value of $n$ trials where each has expected value $p$ is $np$, and the variance of $n$ trials where each has variance $p(1-p)$ is $np(1-p)$. Consequently, the standard deviation goes from $\sqrt{p(1-p)}$ to $\sqrt{np(1-p)}$. But in your setting, you do not consider the sum, but the average ("rate") of $n$ Bernoulli trials. Hence we divide the expected value by $n$, arriving back at $p$; and we divide the standard deviation by $n$ - or equivalently, we divide the variance by $n^2$, which gives us a variance of $\frac{np(1-p)}{n^2}=\frac{p(1-p)}n$.
Intuitively, the more often we repeat a Bernoulli trial, the less does the observed rate deviate from the expected rate.

Comment: Now it is clear. Thank you so much!