# Standard Deviation of the Expected Number of Bernoulli Trials Needed for N successes in a row?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, expected-value, conditional-probability, standard-deviation

The Expected Number of Bernoulli Trials Needed for $n$ successes in a row for any $p$ was answered early by a member and also found in this writeup on page two: https://courses.cit.cornell.edu/info2950_2012sp/mh.pdf

I did not want to crowd the previous post which had two questions and many comments, so this focuses on the standard deviation.

Let $A_n$ be the expected/average/mean number of coin flips/bernoulli trials with probability of success $p$ to get $n$ number of heads in a row.

$A_n=\frac{p^{-n}-1}{1-p}$. $A_n$ take from the pdf:
[image]

**Do the Binomial Distribution formulas for the mean, variance and standard deviation work for this $A_n$ formula that was found?**

**Can I assume the variance is just $\sigma^2 = \mu(1-p)$ with $\mu=A_n$?**

**If yes, then the standard deviation is $\sigma = \sqrt{\mu(1-p)}$ with $\mu=A_n$**

I am not sure it is this straightforward because our expression for the mean is more complex than just $np$.

Comment: The random variable (number of trials until $n$ consecutive successes) is not binomial, so I am not sure why you would think the variance formula for the binomial would be applicable here.

Comment: Ok thank you for the clarification, I heard someone else comment that I needed to apply a version of the equation (d1) to get $A_n^2$ to get the second moment, and then obtain the variance. Does this sound like a good direction? (I have no idea how to do this, though.)

Comment: [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/240081/718169) answer your question?

Comment: Yeah possibly thank you! I see the 2nd post down it talks about computing an expected value of $k$ and computing the expected value of $k(k-1)$. And if we have these, we can add $E(k)$ and $E(k(k−1))$ and subtract the square of $E(k)$ and this gives us the variance. If this works generally and for my expression for $E(k)$, and if I can find $E(k(k−1))$, then that's everything I need. I can pay for help with this to get an answer too